# Why static const members cannot appear in a constant expression like 'switch'

Tags: c++, gcc, constants, switch-statement

I have the following declaration of some static const members

.h

```
class MyClass : public MyBase
{
public:
    static const unsigned char sInvalid;
    static const unsigned char sOutside;
    static const unsigned char sInside;
    //(41 more ...)
}
```

.cpp

```
const unsigned char MyClass::sInvalid = 0;
const unsigned char MyClass::sOutside = 1;
const unsigned char MyClass::sInside = 2;
//and so on
```

At some point I want to use those value in a switch like :

```
unsigned char value;
...
switch(value) {
    case MyClass::sInvalid : /*Do some ;*/ break;
    case MyClass::sOutside : /*Do some ;*/ break;
    ...
}
```

But I get the following compiler error: *error: 'MyClass::sInvalid' cannot appear in a constant-expression*.

I have read other switch-cannot-appear-constant-stuff and didn't find an answer for me since I don't get why those `static const unsigned char` are not constant-expression.

I am using gcc 4.5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problems you see are due to the fact that this

```
static const unsigned char sInvalid;
```

cannot be a compile time constant expression, since the compiler doesn't know its value. Initialize them in the header like this:

```
class MyClass : public MyBase
{
public:
    static const unsigned char sInvalid = 0;
    ...
```

and it will work.

Comment: -1'd by mistake. You should specify that the initialization should be **inside** the class definition, not just the header. If you initialize them in the header, but outside the class, you'll get link errors.

Comment: +1 for a valid solution, but I still thing an enum is better here.

Answer (score 9):

The values are indeed `const`, but they're not **compile-time constants**.

A `switch` condition is resolved at compile-time, not run-time. You can initialize `sInvalid` to whatever value, as long as it's only once, and the `switch` would never know about it until run-time.

It seems like you're better of using `enum`s instead of `static` constants. Besides the fact that it would work, it seems more appropriate design-wise.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable explanation! Enum was my first choice but I am using those constant elsewhere in bite-wise operation and in big array content, I really need them to be `unsigned char`. I never found a way to make it work properly without using explicit `unsigned char` types. Using default Enum and cast it to `unsigned char` everywhere make the code so un-readeable that I cam with this solution.

Comment: can you explain the difference between a constant and a compile-time constant?  (or link to an explanation?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the enum trick to make them compile-time constants :

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    enum {
        sInvalid,
        sOutside,
        sInside,
        //(41 more ...)
    };
};
```

In your code, you can still use the enum to assing to unsigned char, something like this :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char buf[32];
    buf[0] = MyClass::sInvalid; //int to unsigned char
    return buf[0]; //Cast back to int (and avoid a warning a -Wall)
}
```

And use `MyClass::sInvalid` in your swith statements.

Comment: Yeah I really need them to be `unsigned char` and I wasn't able to make `enum MyEnum : unsigned char` work with all the compiler version we are using.

Comment: Switch won't mind. See my edit, compiles with g++ 4.6.1 -Wall